# preg_split with \W and a utf-8 string in PHP 5.1.6: any workaround?

Tags: php, utf-8, pcre

Despite https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php not mentioning it at all, PCRE doesn't seem to work correctly with utf8 strings prior to PHP 5.3.4 even with the 'u' modifier (which is supposed to enable support for utf8 and which according to the abovementioned documentation is available even since PHP 4.something)

```
preg_split("/\W+/u", $someUtf8String)
```

will work as expected on PHP 5.3.4 and above, but will break the string on characters such as ó ò ú í ì and the like, as if they were non-word, on older versions

See:
http://3v4l.org/ERDp5
and if you have doubts (as I do have) about whether or not the string is actually utf8-encoded you can try:
http://3v4l.org/6XnOj
http://3v4l.org/mak33

Either there was a bug which was fixed only in 5.3.4, or utf8 was not supported (in which case I wonder why the 'u' modifier is available at all)

The question is: is there a workaround for older PHP versions?
I need to have \W work correctly on a utf8 string on PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Wow.  PHP 5.1.  Not related to answering your question, but it might be time to plan for an upgrade :)

Comment: To further Ray's point, 5.1.6 was [released in 2006](http://www.php.net/releases/#5.1.6). _Definitely_ time for an upgrade

Comment: I second that. Based on security updates I would most definitely update to AT LEAST 5.3 if possible. Note that the stable version Zend Server offers is 5.4.x so it's most definitely time :P

Comment: @Ray, yeah I know, unfortunately PHP (or at least the way it is packaged for CentOS) makes that a hell of a nightmare, because PHP5.3 and above is a different package that <5.3 (hence it is not possible to just update it) BUT it is incompatible (hence it is not possible to install both alongside), which is intrinsically absurd and wrong. So I have to uninstall current PHP before installing a more recent one, but Plesk makes it impossible due to one little stupid dependency.

Comment: Not saying I cannot upgrade, just saying doing it is a bit of a headache which requires a lot more time and work than it should (which should be just a "yum install" or "yum update" or whatever command line and a few minutes, as upgrading almost anything else)

Comment: note: when I say it is impossible to install alongside, it is not actually completely impossible, I mean it is not possible the simple way it should be, by just installing both packages. It was a tremendously wrong design choice to make  PHP 5.3 *both* a separate package *and* an incompatible one with previous php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `mb_split`?

```
mb_split("\W+", "histórica");
```

*Notice: Without delimiters*

Comment: Hell yes, thanks!! mb_split is the answer; only in this case you have to remove the delimiters ("/" and "/"), so the exact code is:
mb_split("\W+", "whatèver, fóo -- bâr");
Correct output on 4.3.4 - 5.5.7

Comment: @matteo *Sry man I dunno why I commented it!* edited post for the others.